# Unnesting and reducing data structures in javascript

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bubble-chart

I have a dataset regarding wines. For each wine label, I have several information, as country of origin, grapes it is made of, if it is a white or a red wine, its rating, etc. I get this data from a csv. Ultimately, for the visualization I am building, I need a data of the type: Grape | White or Red | Counts. I was able to get the data like this:

```
count: 1
grape: (3) ["Pinot Noir", "Malbec", "Garnacha"]
type: "Red wine"

count: 1
grape: ["Pinot Noir"]
type: "Red wine"

count: 1
grape: ["Pinot Noir"]
type: "Red wine"
```

for each wine label in my dataset. However, I need the data to be like this:

```
count: 1
grape: "Pinot Noir"
type: "Red wine"

count: 1
grape: "Malbec"
type: "Red wine"

count: 1
grape: "Garnacha"
type: "Red wine"

count: 1
grape: "Pinot Noir"
type: "Red wine"

count: 1
grape: "Pinot Noir"
type: "Red wine"
```

So that later I can reduce to this:

```
count: 3
grape: "Pinot Noir"
type: "Red wine"

count: 1
grape: "Malbec"
type: "Red wine"

count: 1
grape: "Garnacha"
type: "Red wine"
```

Is it possible to do that through javascript?

Comment: Instead of showing how you get the data, just copy/paste your CSV (not all of it, just some rows). Since you're probably loading it with `d3.csv` anyway, we can the best and fastest way to get the data structure the way you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following code.

```js
var data = [
  { count: 1, grape: ["Pinot Noir", "Malbec", "Garnacha"], type: "Red wine" },
  { count: 1, grape: ["Pinot Noir"], type: "Red wine" },
  { count: 1, grape: ["Pinot Noir"], type: "Red wine" }
];

var newData = [];

data.forEach(item => {
  item.grape.forEach(g => {
    var addedItem = newData.find(f => f.type == item.type && f.grape == g);
    if (addedItem) {
      addedItem.count += +item.count;
    } else {
      newData.push({
        count: +item.count,
        grape: g,
        type: item.type
      });
    }
  });
});
console.log('Result: ', newData);
```

EDIT: Code can be changed by following for better performance.

```js
var data = [
  { count: 1, grape: ["Pinot Noir", "Malbec", "Garnacha"], type: "Red wine" },
  { count: 1, grape: ["Pinot Noir"], type: "Red wine" },
  { count: 1, grape: ["Pinot Noir"], type: "Red wine" }
];

var counts = {};
data.forEach(item => {
  item.grape.forEach(g => {
    if (counts[item.type]) {
      if (counts[item.type][g]) {
        counts[item.type][g] += +item.count;
      } else {
        counts[item.type][g] = +item.count;
      }
    } else {
      counts[item.type] = { [g]: item.count };
    }
  });
});

var newData = [];
Object.keys(counts).forEach(type => {
  Object.keys(counts[type]).forEach(grape => {
    newData.push({ count: counts[type][grape], grape: grape, type: type });
  });
});
console.log('Result: ', newData);
```

Comment: If this was a tech interview and you mutated a global variable with a function that would be the point where you lost the job.

Comment: Thank you @AdrianBrand. But actually it will be used in a function, so it shouldn't be a global variable. And in some cases, it would be better to use a variable outside of the `loop` to improve the time complexity.

Comment: If you want the best performance you should shape the properties of your counts object as the objects that will appear in the final array and then you can just use Object.values(counts) to create the final array, iterating the array to create an intermediary object only to iterate the properties and create new objects to push into an array is definitely not performance tuning.

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested reduces to get to your final results in one function.

```js
const data = [
  { count: 1, grape: ["Pinot Noir", "Malbec", "Garnacha"], type: "Red wine" },
  { count: 1, grape: ["Pinot Noir"], type: "Red wine" },
  { count: 1, grape: ["Pinot Noir"], type: "Red wine" }
];

const wineCount = data => data.reduce((results, item) => {
  item.grape.reduce((results, grape) => {
    const current = results.find(i => i.grape === grape);
    if (current) {
      current.count++;
    } else {
      results.push({ grape: grape, count: item.count, type: item.type });
    }
    return results;
  }, results);
  return results;
}, []);

console.log(wineCount(data));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be solved by splitting it into 4 distinct steps:

```
// Step 1: 
// [ [{grape, type}, {grape, type}, {grape, type}], [{grape, type}], [{grape, type}] ]
items = items.map(item => {
    return item.grape.map(grape => ({
        grape: grape,
        type: item.type
    }));
});

// Step 2: flatten the array
// [{grape, type}, {grape, type}, {grape, type}, {grape, type}, {grape, type}]
items = items.reduce((acc, arr) => ([...acc, ...arr]), []);

// Step 3: summarize
// {'Pinot Noir': {count, grape, type}, 'Malbec': {count, grape, type}, 'Garnacha': {count, grape, type}}
items = items.reduce((acc, item) => {
    const existingItem = acc[item.grape];
    return {
        ...acc,
        [item.grape]: {
            ...item,
            count: existingItem ? existingItem.count + 1 : 1
        }
    };
}, {});

// Step 4: Get object values
// [{count, grape, type}, {count, grape, type}, {count, grape, type}]
Object.keys(items).map(key => items[key]);
```

Step 1 + 2 together are essentially a flatMap operation:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap
- https://lodash.com/docs/#flatMap

This will give you the intermediate step you defined.

Step 3 + 4 then summarizes the items.